# QTreeWidget проблема с шириной колонок

Tags: qt, gui, qt4

Как сделать так, чтобы у таблицы в QTreeWidget ширина колонок подгонялась под контент (причем у них может быть установлена иконка через setIcon), а одна колонка, скажем, номер N, растягивалась на оставшуюся ширину?
Пытаюсь сделать так:
`header()->setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView::ResizeToContents); // i != N`
`header()->setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView::Stretch); // i == N`

Но те, колонки, у которых установлена иконка, имеют ширину меньше, чем их контент.